# Correct Usage of 'ever'

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is the most appropriate:

1. He is the bravest man to ever exist.
2. He is the bravest man that has ever existed.
3. He is the bravest man ever existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only number 3 is ungrammatical.

For a relative clause where the relativised  element is the subject, *that* or the relative word *who/which* may not be omitted.

As it is, number three gives a passive voice interpretation and since *exist* is an intransitive verb, this produces an undesirable result. Compare:

> He is the bravest man ever interviewed by this magazine.

It could be fixed simply by removing *existed*

> He is the bravest man ever.